# Beginner Java Watch Spring AOP only gets executed once

Tags: java, spring, aop, watchservice

I'm developing a standalone Java Spring application and using Spring's standard AOP implementation.

I am watching a FTP folder for incoming files using Java WatchService and, using AOP, I want to log every file that appears in the FTP.

The issue is that it works for the first file but doesn't work for subsequent files coming into the FTP folder.

The part that monitors the FTP folder is as below:

```
public void monitor() {
    while (key.isValid()) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            if (event.kind() == ENTRY_CREATE)
                downloadService.addToDownloading(event);
            else if (event.kind() == ENTRY_DELETE)
                downloadService.removeFromDownloading(event);
            preprocessorService.stageFiles();
            preprocessorService.processStaged();
            //if 10am file has been detected or it's past 12 then do real processing.
            //create a copy of the collections and clear the ones used for downloading.
            downloadService.printCollections();
        }
        key.reset();
    }
}
```

So basically I want to print to the console every time the "downloadService.addToDownloading(event)" is executed.

So I've defined the following pointcut expression:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* <packageName>.services.DownloadService.addToDownloading(..)) " + "&& args(file)")
public void pointcutTest(Path file) {}
```

and the following uses the Pointcut expression:

```
 @Before("pointcutTest(file)")
 public void test(Path file) {
    System.out.println("File: \n\t" + file.getFileName() + "\nhas appeared in the FTP\n");
}
```

This works when the first file in the FTP folder appears and it prints to the console but it doesn't get executed for subsequent files coming into the FTP.

Is this expected behaviour? How can I make the "test" method execute every time a file appears in the FTP?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `downloadService.addToDownloading` is called multiple times? BTW you call this method with `event` argument but expect argument of type `Path` in pointcut

Comment: Despite the code snippets there is no coherent way to understand what your code does, there are too many loose ends, too many things that could be wrong. Please improve the question by creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make the problem reproduceable, please. Otherwise you waste the time of people like @NikolayShevchenko by keeping him guessing instead of analysing.

Comment: Hey, addToDownloading gets called every time a new file appears in the FTP folder. I originally had a System.out.println in the method and it printed every time a new file appeared. I'll try changing the pointcut and get back to you. That's probably it!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Nikolay Shevchenko was correct. I have two overloaded methods: one that takes Path and one that takes Event. Changing the pointcut to expect a WatchEvent works and is now working as expected. Thanks Nikolay.